# Trigger Airflow DAG on MinIO file upload

Tags: airflow, minio, eventtrigger

I would like to trigger an Apache Airflow DAG when a specific file is uploaded to a specific bucket in MinIO.

I've been looking into MinIO webhooks thinking that might be a solution, but I haven't quite figured it out.

I'm currently working locally, I have a Docker container running MinIO and others running Airflow.

Answer (score 0):

There are no event-based triggers in the Airflow itself.
You should either use external services to trigger Airflow API or just use sensors. In your case, you can use `S3KeySensor`

```
S3KeySensor(
    task_id='s3_file_check',
    poke_interval=60,
    timeout=180,
    soft_fail=False,
    bucket_key=s3_locat,
    bucket_name=s3_buckname,
    aws_conn_id='customer_demo',
    dag=dg
)
```

Comment: Thanks  for the response. Isn't the S3KeySensor only for AWS? As I said, I've got MinIO running locally, so I'm not sure this solution would work.

Comment: It will work. Minio and S3 have the same protocols. Here is the link that explains how to setup minio connection for Airflow: https://blog.min.io/apache-airflow-minio/. After you do this you can use all S3 operators/sensors/hooks etc.